# camera doesn't fit my screen? not sure how to call it

Tags: 3d-view, camera

[image]

so I was following the tutorial in the upper screen and I changed my cam from 1980x1080 to 1080x1080. When andrew does it the camera is fitting still in the monitor?view? whatever the term is. but when I do it it goes off-screen. How do I fix this? I don't know if it matters but I am using a 22 and 27' FHD dualscreen and I and using the bottom 27' monitor for blender

Answer (score 4):

Once your camera is placed, uncheck Lock Camera To View and you can move the camera frame around within the viewport.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! don't know how I didn't think of that